# Added Spring WS Security dependency and now ehcache is failing due to already exists

Tags: spring-security, ehcache, spring-ws

I am new to ehcache, but I added the library org.springframework.ws:spring-ws-security:2.4.0.RELEASE to our project and now the same cache is loading twice, I get the following exception during startup.

Not sure what other information you need, but I can post more.

### Actual Library Added

```
compile ('org.springframework.ws:spring-ws-security:2.4.0.RELEASE') {
        exclude module: 'net.sf.ehcache'
        exclude module: 'org.springframework'
        exclude module: 'org.springframework.ws'
    }
```

Stack Trace:

> Caused by: org.hibernate.cache.CacheException:
>   net.sf.ehcache.CacheException: Another unnamed CacheManager already
>   exists in the same VM. Please provide unique names for each
>   CacheManager in the config or do one of following:
>   1. Use one of the CacheManager.create() static factory methods to reuse same CacheManager with same name or create one if necessary
>   2. Shutdown the earlier cacheManager before creating new one with same name. The source of the existing CacheManager is:
>   DefaultConfigurationSource [ ehcache.xml or ehcache-failsafe.xml ] at
>   org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory.start(EhCacheRegionFactory.java:107)
>   ~[hibernate-ehcache-4.3.10.Final.jar:4.3.10.Final] at
>   org.hibernate.internal.CacheImpl.(CacheImpl.java:70)
>   ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final] at
>   org.hibernate.engine.spi.CacheInitiator.initiateService(CacheInitiator.java:40)
>   ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final] at
>   org.hibernate.engine.spi.CacheInitiator.initiateService(CacheInitiator.java:35)
>   ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final] at
>   org.hibernate.service.internal.SessionFactoryServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(SessionFactoryServiceRegistryImpl.java:91)
>   ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final] at
>   org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:251)
>   ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final] ... 119 common frames
>   omitted Caused by: net.sf.ehcache.CacheException: Another unnamed
>   CacheManager already exists in the same VM. Please provide unique
>   names for each CacheManager in the config or do one of following:
>   1. Use one of the CacheManager.create() static factory methods to reuse same CacheManager with same name or create one if necessary
>   2. Shutdown the earlier cacheManager before creating new one with same name. The source of the existing CacheManager is:
>   DefaultConfigurationSource [ ehcache.xml or ehcache-failsafe.xml ] at
>   net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager.assertNoCacheManagerExistsWithSameName(CacheManager.java:628)
>   ~[ehcache-2.9.0.jar:2.9.0] at
>   net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager.init(CacheManager.java:392)
>   ~[ehcache-2.9.0.jar:2.9.0] at
>   net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager.(CacheManager.java:270)
>   ~[ehcache-2.9.0.jar:2.9.0] at
>   org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory.start(EhCacheRegionFactory.java:91)
>   ~[hibernate-ehcache-4.3.10.Final.jar:4.3.10.Final] ... 124 common
>   frames omitted